# Load Youtube video in parent page in jquery

Tags: youtube-api

To load a youtube player, I use the API in Jquery like this :

```
    var youtube_player = document.createElement("div");
    youtube_player.id = "youtube_player";
    youtube_player.className = "youtube_player";

    document.getElementById('media_container').appendChild(youtube_player);

    var player = {
        playVideo: function (container, videoId) {
            if (typeof (YT) == 'undefined' || typeof (YT.Player) == 'undefined') {
                window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
                    player.loadPlayer(container, videoId);
                };

                $.getScript('//www.youtube.com/iframe_api');
            } else {
                player.loadPlayer(container, videoId);
            }
        },
        loadPlayer: function (container, videoId) {
            new YT.Player(container, {
                videoId: videoId,
                width: 356,
                height: 200,
                playerVars: {
                    autoplay: 1,
                    controls: 1,
                    modestbranding: 0,
                    rel: 0,
                    showInfo: 0
                }
            });
        }
    };

    var id_youtube = get_id_youtube_by_url(url_media);

    player.playVideo(youtube_player.id, id_youtube);
```

And this code is working, a youtube player is created in the div 'media_container'.

But now, if I want to load a youtube player from an iframe in the parent page, it doesn't work.

I think that the problem comes from the attribute "container" in load_player. 
But I don't know how to make this. Have you any idea ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful but try using the sample in this [Github repo](https://github.com/FriesFlorian/viralvideos). It includes searching and playing youtube videos. You can try this [live demo](http://code-tricks.com/dynamically-load-youtube-video-using-jquery/) and compare with your project.